# wmi performance adapter under dotnet process

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2016

what are wmi performance adapters appearing under dotnet process?

[image]

the server has 2 app pools one just https redirect and the other running the actual app. The CPU usage clock close to 100% now and then.